# getstream.io set custom notification sound

Tags: react-native, push-notification, getstream-io

I'm using getStream.io to implement a chat module, but I can't set a custom notification sound on Android. These are the push notification templates that I use:

Notification Template

```
{
  "title": "New message from {{ sender.name }}",
  "body": "{{ truncate message.text 2000 }}",
  "sender": "stream.chat",
  "type": "message.new",
  "version": "v2",
  "message_id": "{{ message.id }}",
  "id": "{{ message.id }}",
  "channel_type": "{{ channel.type }}",
  "cid": "{{ channel_cid }}",
  "channel_id": "{{ channel.id }}",
  "sound": "notification_sound.wav"
}
```

APN Template

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "New message from {{ sender.name }}",
      "body": "{{ truncate message.text 2000 }}"
    },
    "mutable-content": 1,
    "badge": {{ unread_count }},
    "category": "stream.chat",
    "sound": "notification_sound"
  },
  "stream": {
    "sender": "stream.chat",
    "type": "message.new",
    "version": "v2",
    "id": "{{ message.id }}",
    "cid": "{{ channel.cid }}"
  }
}
```

Could you help me, please?